# Is it worth it to create new Class only for sharedPreferences methods?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, static-methods

I'm using sharedPreferences to save my app/game progress and I have 5 different methods to save/load/delete data from sharedPreferences. I'm wondering if it's good practise to create new Class only for those methods and make them static? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are frequently storing a lot of preference values, it can clean up your code if you create a preferences helper class that handles the storage/retrieval of configuration values.  It will keep your code clean, easy to read and give you one single place to maintain your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are saving that much data and find yourself calling those SharedPreferences methods a lot then it might be worthwhile to use SQLite to save data instead.

Comment: I do use both SQLite and SharedPreferences. SharedPrefs for game progress (current level and etc) and SQLite for everything else.